# To alternate biennially? Does word choice suggest BOTH elements in same year?

Tags: word-choice

> 2012 Euro Championship
>
> 2014 World Championship
>
> 2016 Euro Championship
>
> 2018 World Championship

Could I say:

> A Euro Championship and a World Championship alternate bienally.

Or may this sentence leave open the suggestion that every second year BOTH tournaments occur and interchange in that year?

Answer (score 1):

For someone who already knows the cycle, it should make sense. However, it *might* be unclear for someone who is not familiar with the two events or terms.

You could clarify it by saying: ”*The Euro Championship and World Championship are quadrennial events on a biannual alternating schedule.*” or modify the end to ”*events that alternate every two years.*”

The Olympics are on the same schedule so you could reference that for further explanation. Clarifying a concept by using more words to delineate it can be helpful.